# fidn html info with directive in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

i want to find element info with directive .
i put this directive on the label and i need to get elemnt info like `width` and `top` and . . .

now i write this code  in directive:

```
     loadingFactory: ComponentFactory<LoadingComponent>;
  loadingComponent: ComponentRef<LoadingComponent>;

  @Input() set SnipperLoading(data: Promise<any>) {
    // this.containerRef.clear();
    this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    this.loadingComponent = this.containerRef.createComponent(this.loadingFactory);
    data.then(() => {
      this.containerRef.clear();
      this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    });
  }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private containerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {
    this.loadingFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoadingComponent);
    let myCurrentContent: string = el.nativeElement.innerHTML; // get the content of your element

    el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'my new content'; // set content of your element
  }
```

and use the directive like this :

```
      <label *SnipperLoading="user$"> SnipperLoading </label>
```

but when i use this code it show me the `undefined` :

```
  console.log(el.nativeElement.with)
```

.**how can i access to the element info in angular directive ?**

Comment: Are your typos on purpose? (`width` vs `with`)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner no man . i fix that

Comment: I actually meant your provided code.

Comment: I'd advise against putting logic in the constructor of the directive. Use Angular's lifecycle hooks instead, and don't forget that you may need to use ngAfterViewInit to be sure that the view exists before trying to access elements inside it.